# Old .EPS and .AI just need font change -- How?

Tags: fonts, vector, software-recommendation

I have a number of old .EPS files that were created in FreeHand, and some early Illustrator (.AI) files. They use fonts my machine doesn't have. Is there a free app I can use to open them and choose a different font?

The PTB won't buy me an Illustrator license at work, since my job description doesn't include altering graphic files at all. I actually need to do this at least once a week, but on an unpredictable schedule.

I don't really want to rasterize the files, as then I have to retype and reposition all the captions and delete them from the existing image. If I could just update the font they would be fine.

Currently running Mac OS 10.10.5 and Photoshop CS6

Comment: Have you tried opening them with Inkscape? Inkscape can import (single pages of) EPS/AI files. It's free and open source. You could then save them as EPS/PDF files after changing the fonts. Not sure the full AI feature set is supported, but give it a shot...